# How long can one go with necrosis?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, cell-culture, blood-circulation, neurology

In general, when a limb dies, how long does it take before it falls off? Can you go years with a black and useless limb, or does it just.. fall off right away?

Comment: I feel like a study on the mechanics/pathology of gangrene could help here. But I am not an expert in this field but that is where I would start.

Comment: As it is the question cannot be answered, many variables play a role, such as where in the limb the necrosis started, what is the cause, health condition, age, etc. etc..